# How to find percentage from value of a (key,value) pair?

Tags: scala

I want to find a percentage from the value of a key, value pair which is stored in the map.
For eg: Map('a'->10,'b'->20).I need to find percentage occurance of 'a' and 'b'

Comment: I need to calculate the percentage from the value.eg:a=(10/30)*100

Comment: Care to accept an answer? If it has been helpful ! @Nikhil

Answer (score 3):

Adding to Thilo's answer, you can try this below code. The final result will again be a `Map[String, Double]`.

```
val map = Map("a" -> 10.0, "b" -> 20.0)
val total = map.values.sum
val mapWithPerc = map.mapValues(x => (x * 100) / total)
println(mapWithPerc)

//prints Map(a -> 33.333333333333336, b -> 66.66666666666667)
```

Comment: can change the data type to double. Map[String, Double]

Answer (score 1):

```
def mapToPercentage(key: String)(implicit map: Map[String, Double]) = {
   val valuesSum = map.values.sum
   (map(key) * 100) / valuesSum
}

implicit val m: Map[String, Double] = Map("a" -> 10, "b" -> 20, "c" -> 30)

println(mapToPercentage("a")) // 16.666666666666668
println(mapToPercentage("b")) // 33.333333333333336
println(mapToPercentage("c")) // 50
```

[See demo here](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/anLvbHM/0)

Note: there is absolutely no need to curry the function parameters or make the map implicit. I just think it looks nicer in this example. Something like `def mapToPercentage(key: String, map: Map[String, Double]) = {...}` and `mapToPercentage("a", m)` is also perfectly valid. That being said, if you want to get even fancier:

```
implicit class MapToPercentage (map: Map[String, Double]) {
  def getPercentage(key: String) = {
    val valuesSum = map.values.sum
    (map(key) * 100) / valuesSum
  }
}    

val m: Map[String, Double] = Map("a" -> 10, "b" -> 20, "c" -> 30)

println(m.getPercentage("a")) // 16.666666666666668
println(m.getPercentage("b")) // 33.333333333333336
println(m.getPercentage("c")) // 50
```

[See demo here](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/anLvbHM/1)

Point being, the logic behind getting the percentage can be written a few ways:

```
(map(key) * 100) / valuesSum // get the value corresponding to a given key,
                             // multiply by 100, divide by total sum or all values
                             // - will complain if key doesn't exist

(map.getOrElse(key, 0D) * 100) / valuesSum // more safe than above, will not fail
                                           // if key doesn't exist

map.get(key).map(_ * 100 / valuesSum) // will return None if key doesn't exist
                                      // and Some(result) if key does exist
```

Answer (score -1):

```
val map = Map('a' -> 10, 'b' -> 20)

val total = map.values.sum

map.get('a').map(_ * 100 / total)  // gives Some(33)
```

Comment: @RamanMishra also works for key 'b'. Will return None for keys that don't exist.